# Are there any chilli peppers that give an aroma after cooking?

Tags: chili-peppers, aroma

I cooked some bell peppers in a stew and noticed the end result/stew had a nice aroma to it.

I then cooked with sweet pointed peppers and noticed while it did taste sweet, it didn’t really have an aroma like bell peppers.

I cooked with green chilli(not sure which variety) and thought it made the stew taste sweet and grassy, it did not have an aroma.

I’m just wondering

1. Are there any other chilli(or other condiments) which can be used in cooking that will give off a strong aroma and not just taste?
2. Cayenne and chilli peppers are considered to be carminatives, why so if they leave no aroma after cooking?

Comment: Where is the link between *aroma after cooking* and *carminatives*?

Comment: How do you distinguish taste and aroma? As far as I know, taste is what is detected by your mouth (sweet, salty, ...) and aroma is the smell. So I would classify "grassy" as aroma.

Comment: @Tinuviel I thought grassy refers to a sweety/grassy taste given by some chilli.  I just cooked a stew with green chilli and I cant smell it.

Comment: @Johannes_B ok it doesnt say 'after cooking..'.  Are you saying it is only carminative pre cooking?

Comment: @Johannes_B and if so what smell are you referring to?

Comment: @JamesWilson the five basic tastes are sweet, salt, sour, bitter and umami (definition from Wikipedia), so a grassy flavour would be more of a aroma to me (aroma as what your nose detects while eating, not necessarily what you smell while cooking; my first comment was too vague). I just want to make sure we know what your distinction of "taste" and "aroma" is so we talk about the same thing.

Comment: I might just have misunderstoof your statements. Tinuviel was also asking for clarification, so I am not alone.

Comment: Did you actually mean [carminative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carminative)?

Comment: @Sneftel yes, I guess so.

Comment: @Tinuviel seems I have been thinking of grassy as the wrong thing then.  But yes grassy should be an aroma however I dont know what part of a chilli pepper is considered grassy.  Is it that zangy smell when you cut a fresh one open?  And I guess grassy disapears with cooking?